# PenaltyFunction Option in NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, options, undocumented

I am curious if anybody has some experience in using the built-in Option `"PenaltyFunction"` in any of the numerical optimization functions like `NMinimize`.

According to the documentation the user should be able to provide `NMinimize` with a custom penalty function to control the result of the minimization. The default option value is `Automatic`. I tried to find some examples of how to use this `Option`, but there is hardly any information available. The official documentation gives no example.

In the this [Google.group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/EJwb0U-nors/WbuQlvm-hIoJ) post I found the following example, which is not working any more in *Version 10.0.1*.

```
NMinimize[{x + y + z, (1/20)*x + y + 5*z == 100, (x | y | z) ∈ Integers, 
            0 < x < 99, 0 < y < 99, 0 < z < 99}, {x, y, z}, 
 Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "SearchPoints" -> 250}, MaxIterations -> 500]

(* {55., {x -> 20, y -> 19, z -> 16}} *)
```

now with "PenaltyFunction"

```
NMinimize[{x + y + z, (1/20)*x + y + 5*z == 100, (x | y | z) ∈ Integers, 
            0 < x < 99, 0 < y < 99, 0 < z < 99}, {x, y, z}, 
Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PenaltyFunction" -> (100*(#1 - Floor[#1]) &), 
             "SearchPoints" -> 250}, MaxIterations -> 500]
```

This gives a warning of the solution not meeting the constraints and the result (which I don't understand):

```
(* {22., {x -> 20, y -> 1, z -> 1}}*)
```

I tried also to play with the setting myself:

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) I took:

```
 NMinimize[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
 Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]], 
       Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. Last[%]]}]]
```

[image]

Now with some `PenaltyFunction`

```
NMinimize[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[], Method -> {"NelderMead", 
           "PenaltyFunction" -> (Min[#, 0] &)}]
Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]], 
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. Last[%]]}]]
```

[image]

or

```
NMinimize[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[],  Method -> {"NelderMead", 
           "PenaltyFunction" -> ((# - Round[#])^3 &)}]
Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]], 
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. Last[%]]}]]
```

[image]

I can't decide whether I am too stupid or just too lazy to figure out, what `"PenaltyFunction"` actually does. Here my questions:

- What arguments does `"PenaltyFunction"` use/accept?
- How is it possible to penalize individual fitting parameters?
- Do you have any example use cases that shed light on the whole issue?

**EDIT**

I found another Little Piece of Information [here](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/dissertationen/bruemmer-anneke-2010-07-08/PDF/bruemmer.pdf):

The author states that the Default Setting for `"DifferentialEvolution"` is

> ```
> "PenaltyFunction"-> Function[{d,i},d*10^(4*i)]
> ```

Function applied to penalize invalid Parameter values outside constraints (`d` =distance
from allowed value, `i` =number of iteration)

To me it is unclear if this applies to all constraints and how this is usefull.

Comment: Interesting question! I got it to work with 2 arguments : `NMinimize[x^2 - y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
 Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", 
   "PenaltyFunction" -> ((#1^4 + #2^4) &)}]
Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. Last[%]]}]]` which would suggest it can take this as a penalty for points not satisfying the constraint?

Comment: you see that if you flip the penalty `"PenaltyFunction" -> (-(#1^4 + #2^4) &)}` it picks the opposite point?

Comment: @chris Try `ac = {}; NMinimize[{x^2 - y^2, x x + y y <= 1}, {x, y},  Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PenaltyFunction" -> ((AppendTo[ac, {##}]; 1) &)}] ; Print@ac`

Comment: @belisarius This suggest that "PenaltyFunction" takes two(+) arguments: the constraint(s) and the iteration Counter. Right? But why? Any PenaltyFunction could be substituted by a modified constraint. Of course the Iteration dependence could be used to soften/harden the constraints during the minimization. Why would I do this?

Comment: @MarkusRoellig I really don't understand the result. I'm doing some experiments, but I haven't got a better insight

Comment: Related, but *modestly* helpful: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7623/DE_discrete_combinatorial_tutorial.pdf.  I think the penalty function is applied (added to the objective function) only when the point goes *outside* the constraint.  I don't know how Nelder-Mead works, but I suspect it enforces constraints in a way that is clobbered by using your kinds of `"PenaltyFunction"`.  For the unit disk, try `"PenaltyFunction" -> (2(Norm[{##}] - 1) &)`.

Comment: To make it thrash, give it a negative penalty: `"PenaltyFunction" -> (-(Norm[{##}] - 1) &)`

Comment: @MichaelE2 wicked :-D

Comment: Great question! I always wondered about this, in the end giving up and turning to C++...

Answer (score 11):

As noted in the OP, `"PenaltyFunction"` has the form

```
    pf[..., step]
```

where the first argument is constructed from the constraint.
When minimizing an objective function of the form `obj[x,..]`, the actual penalty function is a scaled sum of penalties constructed from `pf[]` and the constraints:

```
Max[1, Abs[obj[x,..]]] * (  (* the objective function scales *)
        (* a sum of *)
        (*   1. penalties for constraints f[x,..] == g[x,..] *)
   pf[Abs[f[x,..] - g[x,..]], step] + ...
        (*   2. penalties for constraints f[x,..] <= g[x,..] *)
   pf[f[x,..] - g[x,..], step] (1 + Sign[f[x,..] - g[x,..]])/2
  )
```

The penalty function is nonnegative and is zero precisely on the domain define by the constraints, unless `pf[]` is zero or negative outside the domain.  (Normally, `pf[]` should be positive.)

We can get the actual penalty function from an internal variable `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`penalty `` (the current step is given by `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`itr ``):

```
myObj[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x + y;
myPenalty[d_?NumericQ, step_?NumericQ] := Abs[d]^step;
NMinimize[myObj[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[],
 Method -> {"NelderMead", "PenaltyFunction" -> myPenalty},
 StepMonitor :> 
  Block[{x, y, Optimization`NMinimizeDump`itr = itr}, 
   Return[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`penalty, NMinimize]]
 ]

(*
  Max[1, Abs[myObj[x, y]]] *
    myPenalty[-1 + x^2 + y^2, itr] * 
     (1 + Sign[-1 + x^2 + y^2])/2
*)
```

Both kinds of constraints:

```
myObj[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := x + y + z;
myPenalty[d_?NumericQ, step_?NumericQ] := Abs[d]^step;
NMinimize[{myObj[x, y, z], z == x^2 + y^2}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  Ball[],
 Method -> {"NelderMead", "PenaltyFunction" -> myPenalty},
 StepMonitor :> 
  Block[{x, y, z, Optimization`NMinimizeDump`itr = itr}, 
   Return[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`penalty, NMinimize]]
 ]

(*
  Max[1, Abs[myObj[x, y, z]]] * (
   myPenalty[Abs[-x^2 - y^2 + z], itr] +
     myPenalty[-1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2, itr] *
      (1 + Sign[-1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2])/2
   )
*)
```

The default penalty function:

```
myObj[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x + y;
NMinimize[myObj[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[],
 StepMonitor :> 
  Block[{x, y, Optimization`NMinimizeDump`itr = itr}, 
   Return[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`penalty, NMinimize]]
 ]

(*
  Max[1, Abs[myObj[x, y]]]*
   2^Floor[itr/10] (-1 + x^2 + y^2)^2 *
    (1 + Sign[-1 + x^2 + y^2])/2
*)
```

***The Google group example***

Here's the actual penalty function from the Google Group example in the OP:

```
NMinimize[{x + y + z, (1/20)*x + y + 5*z == 100,
  (x | y | z) \[Element] Integers, 0 < x < 99, 0 < y < 99, 0 < z < 99},
 {x, y, z}, 
 Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", 
   "PenaltyFunction" -> (100*(#1 - Floor[#1]) &), 
   "SearchPoints" -> 250}, MaxIterations -> 500,
 StepMonitor :> (Hold[{x, y, z}] /. Round[v_] :> v /. 
    Hold[v_] :> Block[v, 
      Block[{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`itr = itr}, 
       Return[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`penalty, NMinimize]]])
 ]

(*
  Max[1, Abs[Round[x] + Round[y] + Round[z]]]* (
    100 (Abs[Round[x]/20 + Round[y] + 5 (-20 + Round[z])] -
        Floor[Abs[Round[x]/20 + Round[y] + 5 (-20 + Round[z])]]) +
     50 (-Floor[-Round[x]] - Round[x]) (1 + Sign[1 - Round[x]]) +
     50 (-Floor[-Round[y]] - Round[y]) (1 + Sign[1 - Round[y]]) +
     50 (-Floor[-Round[z]] - Round[z]) (1 + Sign[1 - Round[z]])
   )
*)
```

Note the last three terms are always zero because `Floor[Round[u]]` is equal to `Round[u]`, when `u` is a real number. What's worse is that the first term is sometimes zero when the variables do not satisfy the constraint, whenever `x` is a multiple of `20` no matter what `y` or `z` are.

This suggests that removing `Floor[#]` from the `"PenaltyFunction"` should improve the performance of `NMinimize`, which it happens to do:

```
NMinimize[{x + y + z, (1/20)*x + y + 5*z == 100,
  (x | y | z) \[Element] Integers, 0 < x < 99, 0 < y < 99, 0 < z < 99},
 {x, y, z}, 
 Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PenaltyFunction" -> (100*#1 &), 
   "SearchPoints" -> 250}, MaxIterations -> 500
 ]

(*  {43., {x -> 20, y -> 4, z -> 19}}  *)
```

Comment: Interesting. Given the solution is posted in 2004, I tested the code in _v5.0_, the correct result is given, and the corresponding penalty function is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWCQz.png Seems that `z` has been eliminated using the constraints in some way, this might explain why the original `"PenaltyFunction` works in _v5.0_.